# Как поочередно изменять значения в списке?

Tags: python-3.x

есть простенький код:

```
word = input('введите слово:')
spis = input('введите список:')
z = 0
huk = []
for i in word:
    huk.append(word[z])
    z = z+1
z = 0
for o in huk:
    huk[z] = spis
    print(huk)
    z = z+1
```

программа заменяет значения в введенном слове на второе введенное пользователем значение, вот что получается на выходе:

```
введите слово:loop
введите список:v    
['v', 'o', 'o', 'p']
['v', 'v', 'o', 'p']
['v', 'v', 'v', 'p']
['v', 'v', 'v', 'v']
```

Программа на выходе полностью изменяет первое введенное слово, но как сделать так, что бы программа изменяла каждый элемент по очереди не меняя остальные, то есть на выходе должно получиться:

```
введите список:v    
['v', 'o', 'o', 'p']
['l', 'v', 'o', 'p']
['l', 'o', 'v', 'p']
['l', 'o', 'o', 'v']
```

Заранее большое спасибо :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
word = input('введите слово:')
spis = input('введите список:')

for i in range(len(word)):
    w = [*word]
    w[i] = spis
    print(w)
```